# Calculating in NP++ with regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

My document has x|y| in the beginning of each line, where x,y are integers between 0 and 300. E.g.:

> 1|1|text1
>
> 1|2|text2
>
> 1|3|text3

Now I want to make the following simple change: Each second number of every line should be subtracted by 1. So the above lines should be changed to

> 1|0|text1
>
> 1|1|text2
>
> 1|2|text3

Is that possible?

Comment: Not in pure regex, no. Regex can't perform arithmetic operations :/

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: I am so happy that I am a vim user.... :) Maybe now it is the right time for you to think about vim? ^_^

Comment: I tried vim, but too heavy for me, notepad ist lighter and faster to learn, thats why it is so successfull, I think. If there is definitely no way, I will change each number manually, only 300 search&replace operations :)

Comment: @Mustafa are you familiar with the `TERMINAL`

Comment: @Mustafa: I have a funny solution, wait a minute

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here's something funny you can do, assuming the text is formatted like you indicated:

- Do a first search and replace, replacing `(\d+\|(\d+)\|.*)` with `####\2\n\1`. this will grab the index and output

  ```
  1|1|text1
  ####1
  1|2|text2
  ####2
  1|3|text3
  ####3
  ```
- do second search and replace to update the index of the row following the `####` marker, replacing

  ```
  ####(\d)\n(\d+\|)\d+(\|.*)
  ```

  with

  ```
  \2\1\3
  ```

You need to update manually the first and last line, and you're good to go !

Since the numbers in the second column are following each other, all you need to do is increment their row.

Comment: Good idea, but does not work in my case, because at some point the numbers are reset to 1 again in the file. But I found another soluton (not with regex), was quite ok for my special case.

Comment: Ok, that was a cool workaround but obviously regex aren't really designed for that. A programming tool is much more suited for the task.

Answer (score 1):

A perl way to do the job:

```
perl -i.back -ape 's/\|(\d+)\|/"|".($1-1)."|"/e' in.txt
```

This replace all second number by this number minus one directly in the file (in.txt).

This file is save before in in.txt.back

Input file before:

```
1|1|text1
1|2|text2
1|3|text3
2|1|text4
3|1|text5
3|2|text6
```

after:

```
1|0|text1
1|1|text2
1|2|text3
2|0|text4
3|0|text5
3|1|text6
```

Comment: Thanks, I should be a bit familiar with pearl I guess.

Comment: @Mustafa: This is just applying the substitution to all the input lines and rewrite them.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can't do math. If the file is huge I suggest you to look into a simple python script or small C++ program to do the parsing job for you. Good luck.

Comment: The file has about 6000 lines, but there are "only" 300 search&replace operations to do. So what would be faster for me as an phython-not-experienced user?

Answer (score 0):

missing awk ??? awwwww !!

```
awk -F'[|]' 'NR % 2 {num = $2-1;print $1"|"num"|"$3}' text.txt
```

where text.txt is the file containing your contents.
you can write the output into a file using the `>` operator

like this

```
awk -F'[|]' 'NR % 2 {num = $2-1;print $1"|"num"|"$3}' text.txt > final.txt
```